# Let 2 Controls automatic fill space with same size

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want two texboxes fill the available Space in a panel. But both have to contain the same width. So `DockPanel` lastchildfill doesn't works here.

I have an image where u can see, i simply created 2 textboxes without any width. The empty Space should be filledby both textboxes like the above (the above is made with manual Width="xxx". But I dont' want to hardcore it like this.

I want it like Grid.Column width="*"
[image]

Do I have to create a `Grid` for each panel? (There will be much more textboxes)

my XAML is simple because I dont know how to realize my idea:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="nachname_textbox"/>
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="vorname_textbox"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Please post your xaml

Answer (score 2):

`UniformGrid` control might suit your needs : it automaticaly places all controls in cells with the same amount of width en height for each ones. And you can define how many rows and columns you want.

```
<UniformGrid Columns=2>
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox/>
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: Thats smaller then making that much Grids. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want two elements to fill 50% each of the avalable width of a `Panel`, you should put a `Grid` with two `ColumnDefinitions` in each `Panel`, i.e. simply replace the `DockPanel` with a `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

If you want to decrease the amount of XAML, you could create your own custom `Grid` class:

```
public class My2x2Grid : Grid
{
    public My2x2Grid()
    {
        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    }
}
```

...and use this one:

```
<local:My2x2Grid>
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: That was the question yea. So there is absolutely no other way? Because the XAML Code will be very big with that much Grids.

Comment: There is no way to make a Panel behave like a Grid without creating one...

Comment: But you could create your own custom Grid class that creates two ColumnDefinitions for you. See my edit.